# How to copy column Data of one Table to another

Tags: sql

I am using the code below:

```
Insert into JV(PurchaseID)
    select PurchaseID from PurchaseReturnDetail
```

But when I execute the query it gives an error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'column1', table 'database.table1'; column does not allow nulls.

Then my INSERT fails. What could be the issue?

Comment: The error is quite clear . . . Other columns in the table cannot be `NULL`.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Can you the table structure of `JV` table with constraints

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JV](
 [JVID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 [JVInvoiceNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [JVDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [StoreID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [BusinessID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [UserID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Currency] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Rate] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
 [DueDate] [datetime] NULL,
 [Reference] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [RefID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 [Narration] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [InvoiceRef] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [PurchaseID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Either the `[JVID]` column should should be auto-generated or You may have to update the table if the record already exists

Answer (score 0):

The error says the table has a non-null constraint for the column.  To change the column to allow nulls, run this query (for Oracle DB):

```
alter table TABLE_NAME modify (COLUMN_NAME null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If first columns is identity column, make sure that auto increment is enabled for that column .

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JV](
    [JVID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JVInvoiceNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [JVDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [StoreID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [BusinessID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [UserID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Currency] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
    [DueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Reference] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RefID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [Narration] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InvoiceRef] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PurchaseID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JVID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```